# Backbone.js behind the scenes

Tags: backbone.js

I read several articles about Backbone.js with sample apps but I can't find an explanation or example on how Backbone knows when a widget in a view is clicked and to which model it is bound.

Is it handled by internal assignment of IDs or something?

For example if you want to delete a div with id="123" could remove it from the DOM with jQuery or javascript functions. In backbone this div could be without the id but could be removed without knowing it, right?

If anybody knows a good article or could improve my understanding on that it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the view "knows" the model to which it's bound is done through the _configure method shown below:

```
_configure: function(options) {
  if (this.options) options = _.extend({}, this.options, options);
  for (var i = 0, l = viewOptions.length; i < l; i++) {
    var attr = viewOptions[i];
    if (options[attr]) this[attr] = options[attr];
  }
  this.options = options;
}
```

The import block to note is:

```
for (var i = 0, l = viewOptions.length; i < l; i++) {
    var attr = viewOptions[i];
    if (options[attr]) this[attr] = options[attr];
}
```

viewOptions is an array of keys that have "special" meaning to a view. Here's the array:

```
var viewOptions = ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName'];
```

This loop is the "glue" between view and model or view and collection. If they're present in the options, they're assigned automatically.

All this is in the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/introduction-to-backbone-js-part-1-models-video-tutorial/.

Even if it looks complicated, there's so little to learn, trust me.

If you ask more specifically I could try to help.

Comment: No, that is not what I was asking. I am already familiar with the basics. I know how it's bound programmatically. But how is it handled internally?

Comment: Ok.. Try reading the "dev" version of backbone.js, the one with the comments etc'.. I'm sure you'll find it. Use a debugger (Chrome/Firebug/IE/etc) as well, obviously. It can't be too mysterious, as it's pretty small.

Comment: I was afraid about this kind of answer. I wanted to read it for human beings without putting too much effort on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source is probably your best bet for improving your understanding. The Backbone function you want to look at is called delegateEvents. But the short version is that it uses the [jQuery delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function. The root element is the View's element (the `el` property), and it's filtered by whatever selector you provided.

jQuery doesn't actually bind a handler to each element that you're listening to. Instead it lets the events bubble up to the root element and inspects them there. Since there's nothing attached to each individual element you can delete them freely without causing any problems. However some methods of deleting the View's element (eg, by setting innerHTML on a parent element) might cause a memory leak. I'm not 100% sure about that, but it's probably best to just not do that anyway.